# Simple C program - help needed

Tags: c, syntax, while-loop

I have a C++ snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char s[2048];
    while (fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin))
    {
        char *pos = strpbrk(s, ">\r\n");
        if (pos != 0)
        {
            char *end = strrchr( pos, '<' );
            if ( end )
                *end = '\0';
            fputs(pos+1, stdout);
        }

        return 0;
    } 
}
```

Although when trimming a text file using it, it works with only 1 line e.g. it trims 1 line only.

If I try to trim multiple lines e.g. file with 30 lines in it, it only trims one line still. I am pretty confused, any help would be appreciated.

Example text file:

```
report2011510222820.html:   <td width="60%" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="tablebody" valign="top">C:\Users\Admin\mon.bat</td>
report2011510222820.html:   <td width="60%" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="tablebody" valign="top">C:\test123.bat</td>
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\Admin\mon.bat
```

Expected Output:

```
C:\Users\Admin\mon.bat
C:\test123.bat
```

Comment: sorry, but this is **NOT** C++, change your tag to C, or really do this correctly in C++

Comment: No, you have a C snippet. :) You can usually get much better answers if you actually tell people what language you're using. As long as you're writing C code, tag the question `[c]`, and ask about C. If you pretend it is C++, then you'll mainly get a lot of answers telling you how your code should be rewritten in C++

Comment: @Nim: There's nothing wrong in using C's IO stuff instead of streams.

Comment: @Mario, I didn't say there was, I just said this is not C++, it's pure C - and hence better tagged as C - or do it properly in C++, no use pretending one is the other...

Comment: @Mario #include <stdio.h> isn't valid C++ however, it would have to be <cstdio>. So this _is_ really C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `return 0;` is inside the `while()` loop so it will always exit after the first run through the loop. You have to move it outside.

To add a line break, replace

```
if ( end )
    *end = '\0';
```

with

```
if ( end )
{
    *end = '\n';
    *(end + 1) = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks, but now all of the strimmed lines appear on 1 line, not on thier orignial lines, what can be done to keep them on thier original line?

Comment: @Mario Hi, Thanks, but now all of the strimmed lines appear on 1 line, not on thier orignial lines, what can be done to keep them on thier original line?

Comment: You'll have to add the linebreak to the end of the lines that you cut off (e.g. by writing a `'\n'` right after the lines). Also note that (for MSVC, don't know your compiler) the runtime will do the `\n`/`\r\n` conversion on the fly so just writing `'\n'` should be enough.

Comment: @James: add printf("\n") after the closing braces below fputs. That should do it.

Comment: @Mario I am using mingw (with Bloodshed frontend), could you give me an example of how to add the line breaks in my code?

Comment: Added. You might have to add the `'\r'` as well in a similar way, but then you should check for the buffer length (replacing only one character and appending the terminator won't overrun the buffer unless it was overrun before).

Comment: @Sriram, Hi I have attempted that but I got "18 E:\myapp.cpp expected `;' before '}' token "

Comment: @James: did you add the semi-colon after the printf statement?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting return 0;` out the the while loop

Answer (score 0):

Yout return is inside the "while" loop
the end of your program should look like:

```
  }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is causing your grief:

```
return 0;
```

If you indented your source correctly, you would be able to see the error much easier. Here it is corrected and indented:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char s[2048];
    while (fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin))
    {
        char *pos = strpbrk(s, ">\r\n");
        if (pos != 0)
        {
            char *end = strrchr( pos, '<' );
            if ( end )
                *end = '\0';
            fprintf(stdout, "%s\r\n", pos + 1); /* Fixed formatting */
         }
   }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you have tagged this as C++ code, but it is actually just plain old C.